# Return Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this piece of code and I need to return the subscribe output as an Observable:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
      Observable.fromPromise(this._WebDBService.sysConfigurazione.toArray()),
      this.getQuantities(params.codart, null, params.udmmodificata, params['qtaord' + params.udmmodificata])
    ).map((
      data: any[]) => {   

        var o = {headers: [], data:[]}

        var art = JSON.parse(data[0][0].ordinidatajson).filter(
          function (itm, index) {
            return itm.codart.v === params.codart;
          }
        );

        art[0].qtaord1.v = data[1].dqta1;
        art[0].qtaord2.v = data[1].dqta2;
        art[0].qtaord3.v = data[1].dqta3;

        o.headers = JSON.parse(data[0][0].ordiniheaderjson);
        o.data = art[0];

        return o;
      }
    ).subscribe(
      data =>
      {
        return data;  //RETURN THIS !!!
      }
    );
```

What I have to to is to incapsulate the above code in a function method that returns an Observable:

```
public getOrderRow(params): Observable<any>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: not possible, in order to not change the method signature you will have to subscribe outside of the method

Comment: do you need that subscription at the end or is it just for the sake of question?

Comment: return it to what? this doesn't make any sense.  Just return the Observable stream itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
getObs() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      Observable.fromPromise(this._WebDBService.sysConfigurazione.toArray()),
      this.getQuantities(params.codart, null, params.udmmodificata, params['qtaord' + params.udmmodificata])
    ).map((
      data: any[]) => {   

        var o = {headers: [], data:[]}

        var art = JSON.parse(data[0][0].ordinidatajson).filter(
          function (itm, index) {
            return itm.codart.v === params.codart;
          }
        );

        art[0].qtaord1.v = data[1].dqta1;
        art[0].qtaord2.v = data[1].dqta2;
        art[0].qtaord3.v = data[1].dqta3;

        o.headers = JSON.parse(data[0][0].ordiniheaderjson);
        o.data = art[0];

        return o;
      }
    );
}
```

then consumers can just get the observable and subscribe like:

```
getObs().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

but, you cannot return the data from an asynchronous operation in a synchronous manner.